# I'm a mix of several mixes - What can I be?

Tags: riddle

> First and foremost, I'm a mix of mixes.
>
> My first mix consists of what I have one, and what I have seven
>
> What is subject to change,
>
> The result of eels and a madman.
>
> After that, I am a mix of love and music
>
> Of grace and agility,
>
> Of shaking and screaming.
>
> My last is a mix of everything
>
> Multitudes of genres
>
> And yes, the answer is one.

It's abbreviated to 3 letters.

Hint I:

> what I have one, and what I have seven: look at that blue box.

Hint II

> The result of eels and a madman.: think <s>Marvel</s> Spiderman

Comment: Ok... I'm gonnna try the whole "don't overthink it" thing and say the answer is "one"? XD

Comment: For the first hint: the OP has `bar tbyq naq frira fvyire onqtrf (rot13)`

Comment: Correct... now whats tbyq and fvyire mixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Electronic Dance Music?

My first mix consists of what I have one, and what I have seven 
What is subject to change,
The result of eels and a madman.

> As @tmpearce pointed out, OP has 1 gold badge and 7 silver badges. The combination of gold and silver is called "electrum". Electro is a Spiderman villain who, in one version, gets his electricity-themed powers from electric eels.

After that, I am a mix of love and music 
Of grace and agility,
Of shaking and screaming.

> These could all be descriptions of 'dance'.

My last is a mix of everything
Multitudes of genres

> Music indeed has multitudes of genres.

It's abbreviated to 3 letters.

> EDM is commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> Book?

First and foremost, I'm a mix of mixes.

> A book contains a massive mix of letters and words.

My first mix consists of what I have one, and what I have seven

> Chapters

What is subject to change,

> The plot chan change. Who doesn't love a plot twist!

The result of eels and a madman.

> Comedy

After that, I am a mix of love and music

> Romance

Of grace and agility,

> Fantasy

Of shaking and screaming.

> Horror

My last is a mix of everything

> The last page is often taken up of other books

Multitudes of genres

> There are many book genres

And yes, the answer is one.

> A book is a combination of all of these, brought together by the author

Comment: It is not- think completely different